# JSONObject can't be correctly created

Tags: android, json

I want to get images from server into my Android app. 
My first steps are:

I have this JSON string array from [server](https://augmentedandroidapp.000webhostapp.com/)

`{"results":"[{\"url\":\"https:\\\/\\\/augmentedandroidapp.000webhostapp.com\\\/images\\\/kamara1.jpg\"},{\"url\":\"https:\\\/\\\/augmentedandroidapp.000webhostapp.com\\\/images\\\/kamara2.jpg\"},{\"url\":\"https:\\\/\\\/augmentedandroidapp.000webhostapp.com\\\/images\\\/kamara3.jpg\"}]"}`

I got urls in my App from server with code below and working fine.

```
  private void getURLs() {
    class GetURLs extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        ProgressDialog loading;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(GalleryTargets.this, "Loading...", "Please Wait...", true, true);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(GalleryTargets.this,s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            imageJSON = s;
            Log.e(LOGTAG, "Succeed Read url" + imageJSON);         
            extractJSON(imageJSON);
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String uri = strings[0];
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(uri);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                String json;
                while ((json = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(json);
                }
                return sb.toString().trim();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    GetURLs gu = new GetURLs();
    gu.execute(newurl);
}
```

But, i want to extract json into a new JSON Object with this method below but throws the exception, Json object not created.
Any ideas why this exception happens? 
Thank you in advance!

```
private void extractJSON(String jsonString){
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        JSONArray jArray  = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject oneObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            oneObject.getString("url");//
        }
        Log.e(LOGTAG, "JsonArray Succeed" );

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(LOGTAG, "JsonArray exception");

    }
}
```

Comment: please post exception and sack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `JSONArray jArray  = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");`
Try `JSONArray jArray  = new JSONArray (jsonObject.getString("results"));`

You're asking for a json array but it is a string.

Answer (score 0):

> There is an error on the json.. after "results": there must not be
>   quotes

This is correct

```
{"results":[{\"url\":\"https:\\\/\\\/augmentedandroidapp.000webhostapp.com\\\/images\\\/kamara1.jpg\"},{\"url\":\"https:\\\/\\\/augmentedandroidapp.000webhostapp.com\\\/images\\\/kamara2.jpg\"},{\"url\":\"https:\\\/\\\/augmentedandroidapp.000webhostapp.com\\\/images\\\/kamara3.jpg\"}]}
```